# ¿Cómo ejecuto un include de PHP desde un onclick de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, php5

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar el inlude de PHP en JavaScript, sin un formulario?. Se que se puede hacer con ajax, pero no se como.

```
<li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#dashboard" role="button" onclick="<?php include 'login.php'; ?>"><b>Dashboard</b></a></li>
```

Comment: creo que eso ne es muy optimo de hacer lo que debes pensar en donde debes darle el include para que carge todo lo que necesitas.

Comment: y si en lugar cargas los datos y los ocupas y en el onclick solo quitas el hide??? de esta manera no tendrías que hacer un request al backend, saludo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: ¿que se supone que trae el include?